# update 2nd item when the 1st item is the same - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My main state:

```
this.state = {
  list: []
}
```

I have a form w/c takes 2 separate arguments: listItem and quantity

```
 render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
        <form onSubmit={this.handleAddOption}>
           <input type="text" placeholder="description" name="description" /> <br/>
           <input type="number" placeholder="quantity" name="quantity" />  <br/><br/>
           <button>Add Grocery</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So basically the two forms are being submitted to the `handleAddOption` function:

```
handleAddOption(description, quantity){
    if (!description && !quantity) {
      return 'Enter valid description and quantity to add item';
    } else if (this.state.list.indexOf(description) > -1) {
      // must update the quantity
    }

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      list: prevState.list.concat(description, quantity)
    }));
  }
```

So basically the list is an array. There are two things I want to do here:
  1. I need to add this two to my main array list state and render them side by side on the screen like:

```
  item1 1
  item2 2
```

As of the moment, I am only concatenating both as text w/c is not a good idea since I need to update the quantity later.

2. I want to find a way to update the quantity if the same description was placed to the to the form for instance:

   1st Input:
   item1 1

   2nd Input:
   item1 5

So it must update the item1 quantity to 5

Any idea how I can handle this?

Comment: Any reasons why you're not putting objects like `{description, quantity}` into the `list` array and putting it as text?

Answer (score 0):

In order to save the information to an array, we need to figure out the location of the description inside of the array.

You're using the concat function in your example. This function add the two items to the array, but as separate entries. I would recommend you to save the information to a dictionary, this combines the values into a single entry. In JavaScript, we can do this using objects:

```
prevState.list.push({
    description: description,
    quantity:    quantity
});
```

In order to get the description from the object, we use the dot notation. 
We would save an object to a variable, let's name it entry, and access the description like:

```
entry.description
```

In order to make this work, we are supposed to change the function a little bit. Since we can't just check for the presence of a value, we need to loop over the entries of the list. When we do, we have to check whether the descriptions match, if none does, we add the new entry

```
handleAddOption(description, quantity){
    var hasBeenFound = false;

    prevState.list.forEach(function (entry) {
        if (entry.description === description) {
            hasBeenFound = true;
            entry.quantity = quantity;
        }
    });

    if (!hasBeenFound) {
        elements.push({description: description, quantity: quantity})
    }
}
```

I hope my description made a little sense and that you are able to continue.

Comment: prevState is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Your handleAddOption function edit like this.

```
handleAddOption = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let description = e.target[0].value;
    let quantity = e.target[1].value;

    if (!description && !quantity) {
      return 'Enter valid description and quantity to add item';
    } else {
        const list = this.state.list.map((el, i) => {
            if (el.indexOf(description) > -1) {
            // must update the quantity
            }
            return (el)
        });
    }    
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      list: prevState.list.concat(description + ' ' + quantity)
    }));
}
```